# Mathematical way applied to current physical measures to change a spin from $s$=1 to $s$=2?

Tags: angular-momentum, hilbert-space, quantum-spin, semiconductor-physics, laser

I read about [*Spin Modulation in Semiconductor Lasers*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.0719).

I'm interesting to understand better a mathematical way (not physical techniques) applied to current physics technologies measures methods to change a spin from $s$=1 to $s$=2 or in general from a spin $s$=x to another value of spin $s$=y
Obviously for the mathematicians just write $s$ = 1 and then $s$ = 2, but the physicists have to make physical measurements, so they have to carry the mathematical formula finding the physical version of the function. 
I'm looking for this for spin.